# Efficiently Check Bitflag Invariant (possible bit-twiddle)

Tags: c, performance, bit-manipulation, bitflags

I have a `byte` I am using to store bit flags. I have 8 flags (one for each bit) that can be divided into 4 pairings of 2 flags which are mutually exclusive. I have arranged the bit flags in the following fashion:

```
ABCDEFGH
10011000
```

Flag A cannot be set while flag B is also set, the converse is also true, hence flags A & B are mutually exclusive. *Flags A & B could both be unset, just not both be set.* The same rules are true of flags C & D, flags E & F, and flags G & H.

**Current test case (in C):**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int check(char b) { // used to check invariant
  return ((b&0xC0)==0xC0||(b&0x30)==0x30||(b&0x0C)==0x0C||(b&0x03)==0x03)?0:1;
}
int main() {
  char input[256] = {
  0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x09,0x0a,0x0b,0x0c,0x0d,0x0e,0x0f,
  0x10,0x11,0x12,0x13,0x14,0x15,0x16,0x17,0x18,0x19,0x1a,0x1b,0x1c,0x1d,0x1e,0x1f,
  0x20,0x21,0x22,0x23,0x24,0x25,0x26,0x27,0x28,0x29,0x2a,0x2b,0x2c,0x2d,0x2e,0x2f,
  0x30,0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34,0x35,0x36,0x37,0x38,0x39,0x3a,0x3b,0x3c,0x3d,0x3e,0x3f,
  0x40,0x41,0x42,0x43,0x44,0x45,0x46,0x47,0x48,0x49,0x4a,0x4b,0x4c,0x4d,0x4e,0x4f,
  0x50,0x51,0x52,0x53,0x54,0x55,0x56,0x57,0x58,0x59,0x5a,0x5b,0x5c,0x5d,0x5e,0x5f,
  0x60,0x61,0x62,0x63,0x64,0x65,0x66,0x67,0x68,0x69,0x6a,0x6b,0x6c,0x6d,0x6e,0x6f,
  0x70,0x71,0x72,0x73,0x74,0x75,0x76,0x77,0x78,0x79,0x7a,0x7b,0x7c,0x7d,0x7e,0x7f,
  0x80,0x81,0x82,0x83,0x84,0x85,0x86,0x87,0x88,0x89,0x8a,0x8b,0x8c,0x8d,0x8e,0x8f,
  0x90,0x91,0x92,0x93,0x94,0x95,0x96,0x97,0x98,0x99,0x9a,0x9b,0x9c,0x9d,0x9e,0x9f,
  0xa0,0xa1,0xa2,0xa3,0xa4,0xa5,0xa6,0xa7,0xa8,0xa9,0xaa,0xab,0xac,0xad,0xae,0xaf,
  0xb0,0xb1,0xb2,0xb3,0xb4,0xb5,0xb6,0xb7,0xb8,0xb9,0xba,0xbb,0xbc,0xbd,0xbe,0xbf,
  0xc0,0xc1,0xc2,0xc3,0xc4,0xc5,0xc6,0xc7,0xc8,0xc9,0xca,0xcb,0xcc,0xcd,0xce,0xcf,
  0xd0,0xd1,0xd2,0xd3,0xd4,0xd5,0xd6,0xd7,0xd8,0xd9,0xda,0xdb,0xdc,0xdd,0xde,0xdf,
  0xe0,0xe1,0xe2,0xe3,0xe4,0xe5,0xe6,0xe7,0xe8,0xe9,0xea,0xeb,0xec,0xed,0xee,0xef,
  0xf0,0xf1,0xf2,0xf3,0xf4,0xf5,0xf6,0xf7,0xf8,0xf9,0xfa,0xfb,0xfc,0xfd,0xfe,0xff};

  char truth[256] = {
  1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,
  1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,
  1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,
  1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,
  1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,
  1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,
  1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

  int i,r;
  int f = 0;
  for(i=0; i<256; ++i) {
    r=check(input[i]);
    if(r != truth[i]) {
      printf("failed %d : 0x%x : %d\n",i,0x000000FF & ((int)input[i]),r);
      f += 1;
    }
  }
  if(!f) { printf("passed all\n");  }
  else   { printf("failed %d\n",f); }
  return 0;
}
```

The `check()` method above currently passes all the test cases. I want to know if there is a more efficient way to check that this invariant is true using some bit-twiddling hack. I may have to check this invariant many times a second so efficiency is important. I am willing to permute the arrangement of the flags if the new arrangement allows for a bit twiddling hack that the original arrangement did not.

Permutation EX: `ABCDEFGH` --> `AHBGCFDE`

Comment: Take a look at http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't profiled this, so no promises, but you could try:

```
int check(char b)
{
    return ! ( (b << 1) & b & 0xaa );
}
```

You could do away with the inversion `!` if you accepted non-zero (not just 1) as a fail, and zero as a pass.

Alternatively, you could just use the lookup table you already generated:

```
int check(char b)
{
    return truth[(unsigned char)b];
}
```

Whatever you try, please profile!

(oh, and I'd recommend using unsigned chars rather than signed chars for storing bit-fields like this, as the behaviour is better defined for things like bit-shifts and booleans. Most compilers will probably do what you expect, but better safe than sorry).

Comment: Your bit-twiddle passed all test cases! I don't want to use the look-up table for memory reasons. The look-up table was just for testcases.

Comment: @wildplasser as written in the original post, the function should return 1 for pass, 0 for fail, so I kept to that to pass the testing function. If the logic could be inverted, and non-zero was acceptable instead of strictly '1', you could indeed do away with the invert. I'll add a note.

Comment: You are correct. Initially, I did not scroll to the right. (and I am used to check functions to return 0 for success)

Comment: @awashburn What I mean is, please check to make sure it actually helps your code, i.e. by timing it to see if it's faster, or looking at the code generated to see if it's better.

Comment: Even better: Check if any such opaque piece of code (some poor soul will need to understand it later on) really is worth the gain.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially have four tristate values: either option 1 is set, or option 2 is set, or neither.  You might want to consider using bit fields in a struct to explicitly get nsigned integers of two bits each to track these tristates:

```
struct Flags {
    unsigned opt1: 2;
    unsigned opt2: 2;
    unsigned opt3: 2;
    unsigned opt4: 2;
};
const unsigned NEITHER = 0;
const unsigned FIRSTOPT = 1;
const unsigned SECONDOPT = 2;
const unsigned INVALIDOPT = 3;
```

With this setup, your question boils down to checking that all four fields are not equal to INVALIDOPT.  Your check function could thus be

```
bool IsValid(struct Flags flags) {
    return flags.opt1 != INVALIDOPT &&
           flags.opt2 != INVALIDOPT &&
           flags.opt3 != INVALIDOPT &&
           flags.opt4 != INVALIDOPT;
}
```

This also means that instead of twiddling bits to set which option is selected, you can just do normal variable reads and writes with the named constants.  It should be much easier and much safer.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To prevent it in the first place:

```
#define NONE_SET 0 // 00
#define FIRST_SET 1 // 10
#define SECOND_SET 2 // 01

int magic(int AB, int CD, int EF, int GH) {
  return (((AB*3+CD)*3+EF)*3+GH)*3
}
```

Better yet, use an `enum` instead of `#define`s

Example invocation (e.g. for ABCDEFGH=10000100)

```
int magic_number = magic(FIRST_SET, NONE_SET, SECOND_SET, NONE_SET);
```

no bit twiddling, just some multiplications. (This can obvoiusly be automated)

If you just want to check if pairs of bits in a byte are not both set:

```
uint8_t in; // the input byte
uint8_t out = in & (in >> 1) & 0x55; 
// if out != 0, the invariant is violated
```

note: 0x55 is 01010101 in binary (i.e. we are masking off adjacent pairs like BC, leaving only those like AB and CD)